# python's .replace leaves empty lines

Tags: python, string, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to pull data from a website. The unadulterated version comes like this:

```
{eps: 25}
{eps:[]}
{eps:[]}
{eps:[]}
{eps: 50}
{eps:[]}
{eps:[]}
{eps:[]}
```

Now I am not sure why the blank ones show up, but I am able to remove them with .replace. The issue is when I use `.replace` the result is like this:

```
25



50



# Code comment to show extra spaces.
```

I've tried `.split`, `.sub`, `.strip` to no avail. I'm not sure what else to try.

UPDATE:

Adding source code

```
# coding: utf-8
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import re
import csv
import urlparse
from stockscrape.items import EPSItem

class epsScrape(BaseSpider):
        name = "eps"
        allowed_domains = ["investors.com"]
        ifile = open('test.txt', "r")
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        start_urls = []
        for row in ifile:
                url = row.replace("\n","")
                if url == "symbol":
                        continue
                else:
                        start_urls.append("http://research.investors.com/quotes/nyse-" + url + ".htm")
        ifile.close()

        def parse(self, response):
                f = open("eps.txt", "a+")
                sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
                sites = sel.select("//tbody/tr")
                items = []
                for site in sites:
                        item = EPSItem()
                        item['eps']  = site.select("td[contains(@class, 'rating')]/span/text()").extract()
                        strItem = str(item)
                        newItem = strItem.replace(" ","").replace("'","").replace("{eps:[","").replace("]}","").replace("u","").replace("\\r\\n",'').replace('$
                        f.write("%s\n" % newItem)
                f.close()
```

text.txt has a stock symbols in it like this:

```
MSFT
A
H
```

so on and so forth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Empty lines contain newlines; replace the `\n` too.

If you find that you are end up removing **all** newlines, then split on newlines and remove any empty string values:

```
outputstring = '\n'.join([line for line in inputstring.splitlines() if line.strip()])
```

This removes any empty lines, rejoining the remaining non-empty lines with fresh newlines.

If instead you are producing the output line by line by printing or writing to a file, simply *not print or write* when the line is empty:

```
newItem = newItem.replace(.., ..)
if newItem.strip():
    print newItem
    f.write('{}\n'.format(newItem))
```

The `if` statement tests for a line that contains more than just whitespace.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, .replace('\n','') does nothing

Comment: @Resin: How are you producing the output? As one big string, or printing line by line?

Comment: @Resin: without seeing your exact code, I cannot say more, I am afraid.

Comment: I am printing it line by line. If I write it to a file like this f.write(newItem) it comes out 2550.... so on an so forth. If I do f.write("%s\n" % newItem) it does the above. Ill clean up what I have and post it.

Comment: @Resin: Then you can use the `if newItem.strip():` test.

Comment: The if newItem.strip(): worked. I guess the strip() didnt actually remove anything, it would just fail out.